# Spring application ALWAYS responds with status 200

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, jwt

I am currently developing a spring boot backend application that supports Spring security's JWT authentication.

My problem started after implementing the required classes to get the JWT authentication, but the problem started there.

Here's the classes that I added, the first code snippet is about the configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig  {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJWT authEntryPointJWT;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authentificationJwtTokenFilter(){
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPointJWT).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider((authenticationProvider()));
        http.addFilterBefore(authentificationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The second is the implementation of the filter:

```java
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)){
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentification : {}", e);
        }
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the `jwthelper` class:

```java
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    private final String jwtSecret="change_me";

    private int jwtExpirationMs=3600;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the controller method for the authentication:

```java
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public JwtResponse authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody  LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getUsername()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(jwt);
        JwtResponse returnStatement = new JwtResponse(jwt,  userDetails.getUsername(), roles);
        return returnStatement;
    }
```

Now I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the request filtering process, I just fail to see where exactly. Please help :)

Comment: i would strongly recommend that you instead use the built in JWT features of spring security than writing custom security https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into it. 
I guess it'll be easier to integrate a LADP server with the built in spring security feature? If you could provide me with some exemples or documentation I will be very grateful to you sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the implementation of your `AuthTokenFilter`, in the method `doFilterInternal`, you're not calling `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);`
This method must always be called in a filter, otherwise the application won't continue in its chain of filters and return a default response, 200 in your case.